# App Service sending 500.30 error when trying to use Managed Identity in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

The customer is trying to use Managed Identity to access to Azure Resource by following the links below.

- [Connecting from your application to resources without handling credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview-for-developers?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet)
- [Tutorial: Access Azure services from a .NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal)

But they face the following error after updating the code:

```
"HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start"
```

I also tried and faced the same issue.
The customer is using 3.1 and I am using 6.0.
(Without adding anything to use Managed Identity, there is no issue to deploy. Once adding something in code, it returns error message)

1. Is there any step we should take which is not listed in the link above?
2. Where to add the code in the link below? It is not "Program.cs"? Can anyone share the whole sample code?
   "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview-for-developers?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet#accessing-a-blob-in-azure-storage"
3. I am not familiar with .Net and I don't know where I can find "console.write" return in App Service. Could you please let me know? I don't get error in App Service with the below code, but once I add the code to upload file, I receive 500.30 error. I would like to check "blobClient1" is returning blob content or not, but I don't know where I can find the return(Try with Kudo, but not sure where to find).

```
var clientID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my client id");
var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{ ManagedIdentityClientId = clientID };

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions);

var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(https://storageadfuat.blob.core.windows.net), credential);
BlobContainerClient containerClient1 = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("blob container name");
BlobClient blobClient1 = containerClient1.GetBlobClient("blob name");

Console.Write("test", blobClient1);
```

Try to use Managed Identity with App Service and Azure Resources(ASP.NET). But once add the code by following the document, we receive 500.30 error message. Hopefully getting more clear sample code and manage to use the Managed Identity without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below steps to use Managed Identity in `ASP.Net` to Access Blob Storage.

- Created `ASP.Net CORE Web App and deploy the App to Azure App service.
- Make sure Managed Identity is enabled on the deployed App Service.

[image]

- I have a `Contibutor` Role, which grants full access to all the resources. So, I haven't set any permissions.

[image]

- If you are using MVC Application, write the code in `Controller.cs` else write it in  `Program.cs` file only.
- The code which you are following is trying to get the `blob` which is in the container.
- In `Storage Account`, create a container.

[image]

- Inside the `Container` which you have created, upload blobs. Blob is nothing but a `file/doc` which you have uploaded.

[image]

[image]

- Copy the `ConnectionString` from `Storage Account` => `Access keys` .Click on show, icon to copy the `connectionstring` will be visible.
  [image]

***My Program.cs file***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Store the Connection string in `appsettings.json` and get the value here. For now I have given connection string in `Program.cs` itself.
 
string mysaconn = "YourConnectionString from Storage Account";
string containername = "mycontainer";

BlobServiceClient serviceClient1 = new BlobServiceClient(mysaconn);
BlobContainerClient containerClient1 = serviceClient1.GetBlobContainerClient(containername);
var blobs = containerClient1.GetBlobs();
foreach(var blob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
    BlobClient blobclient1 = containerClient1.GetBlobClient(blob.Name); 
}
Console.Read();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");   
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

- Re-deploy the App and run the Application.
- In local `Console.WriteLine` shows the output in the Output window. And in production (Azure App Service) it doesn't show any output.

***Local Output***

[image]